# Word macro crashed

Tags: vba, ms-word, crash, freeze

Is there a mistake in my macro? i just need some words to be highlighted!
the page goes black and sometimes after 6 to 10 min it comes back but most times i have to close word with task manager

```
Sub HighlightWords()
    Dim Word As Range
    Dim WordCollection(17) As String
    Dim Words As Variant

    'Define list.
    'If you add or delete, change value above in Dim statement.
    WordCollection(0) = "Exhibit"
    WordCollection(1) = "with regard"
    WordCollection(2) = "reviewer"
    WordCollection(3) = "instruction"
    WordCollection(4) = "subrogation document"
    WordCollection(5) = "montreal"
    WordCollection(6) = "quebec"
    WordCollection(7) = "Final"
    WordCollection(8) = "document"
    WordCollection(9) = "me"
    WordCollection(10) = "service"
    WordCollection(11) = "improvement"
    WordCollection(12) = "inc"
    WordCollection(13) = "tenant's improvement"
    WordCollection(14) = "Inc."
    WordCollection(15) = "Mrs."
    WordCollection(16) = "Policy"
    WordCollection(17) = "clause"
    
    'Set highlight color.
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
    
    'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    'Set highlight to replace setting.
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
    
    'Cycle through document and find words in collection.
    'Highlight words when found.
    For Each Word In ActiveDocument.Words
        For Each Words In WordCollection
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = Words
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With

            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        Next

    Next

    

End Sub
```

i think something is wrong in the macro!

Comment: Your outer loop is pointless.  You're not using the loop variable  `Word`.  All it's doing is repeating the inner code by however many words are in your document.

Comment: now it's giving me the Compile error: End With without With

Answer (score 1):

remove the outer loop and it will work.
(I've also expanded the `With Selection.Find` bit to include more of the code)

```
Sub HighlightWords()
    'Dim Word As Range    this isn't actually needed
    Dim WordCollection(17) As String
    Dim Words As Variant

    'Define list.
    'If you add or delete, change value above in Dim statement.
    WordCollection(0) = "Exhibit"
    WordCollection(1) = "with regard"
    WordCollection(2) = "reviewer"
    WordCollection(3) = "instruction"
    WordCollection(4) = "subrogation document"
    WordCollection(5) = "montreal"
    WordCollection(6) = "quebec"
    WordCollection(7) = "Final"
    WordCollection(8) = "document"
    WordCollection(9) = "me"
    WordCollection(10) = "service"
    WordCollection(11) = "improvement"
    WordCollection(12) = "inc"
    WordCollection(13) = "tenant's improvement"
    WordCollection(14) = "Inc."
    WordCollection(15) = "Mrs."
    WordCollection(16) = "Policy"
    WordCollection(17) = "clause"
    
    'Set highlight color.
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
    
With Selection.Find
    'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    'Set highlight to replace setting.
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
    
    'Cycle through document and find words in collection.
    For Each Words In WordCollection
        .Text = Words
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: now it's giving me the Compile error: End With without With

Comment: Strange, works fine for me. You've definitely copied the entire code and not added / merged anything in?

Comment: I had a mistake , you are right and it works like a charm! Thank you soooooo Much! THANK YOU!